# Propel ORM - Custom where clause

Tags: mysql, propel

I'm trying to match md5(ID) to an id.

```
SELECT *
FROM `user` u
WHERE
MD5(`user_id`) = '66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799'
```

this is ID = 58

I tried something like this. I know I'm close I just don't know what I'm missing

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAnd('md5('.User::USER_ID.')', $_REQUEST['fs'], Criteria::CUSTOM);
$user = UserPeer::doSelectOne($criteria);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lenghty T&E process I managed to get it done like this

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(UserPeer::USER_ID, "md5(user.user_id) = \"".$_REQUEST['fs']."\"", Criteria::CUSTOM); // risk of SQL injection!!
$saved_search = UserPeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

For some reason PropelORM though that $_REQUEST['fs'] was name of the table rather than the value. **\""** solved the problem.

Comment: Why not just localize the hash value into a new var, then pass it to the criteria object? Localize: `$userPassword = md5($_REQUEST['fs']);` then pass to criteria object: `$c->add(UserPeer::USER_PASSWORD, $userPassword, Criteria::EQUALS);` By the way, you don't have to worry about sql injection if you do it this way, because the hash string will be passed, not the actual value to be hashed.

Comment: Because password is clear text and I want to MD5(password) field to compare. This is just an example I do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Agreed, plain text passwords is a bad idea. But you can hash before you send to the query, to compare against the hash you have in the database.

Comment: @MikePurcell I agree. Password example was a bad idea. USER_ID would be much better - changed that now. I also do use private_key that i combine with ID itself to make sure people can't just generate their own md5 digests. Anyway, this solves the problem not sure why the other approach didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, directly using Criteria objects is <strike>deprecated</strike> not recommended. You should use [Active Query classes](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html).

Using these classes, you will be able to write stuff like this :

```
UserQuery::create()
  ->where('md5(User.Password) = ?', $_REQUEST['fs'], PDO::PARAM_STR)                                                
  ->findOne();
```

You'll notice that I use the PhpName both of the table and the column in the query.

EDIT : For raw conditions, the parameter type has to be specified. You'll find more information on [this issue](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/pull/182).

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause 'md5(User.PASSWORD) = ?''

Comment: It's no more recommended, not deprecated.